# Warum "den", nicht "der"?

Tags: grammatical-case, past-participle

> Vor hundert Jahren schliefen die Menschen im Schnitt neun Stunden, vor zwanzig Jahren waren es noch mehr als acht, heute sind es sieben, **den** verlängerten Wochenend-, Feiertags und Urlaubsschlaf eingerechnet.

Sollte es nicht, *der* sein? Warum *den*?

Quelle : https://bit.ly/2YRHtbV

Comment: Wie meinst du das, etwa ***der*** *Sieben jeden Schlaf eingerechnet*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Partizipialkonstruktionen

Man würde vermuten, daß es sich bei

> den verlängerten Wochenend-, Feiertags und Urlaubsschlaf eingerechnet

um eine *satzwertige Partizipphrase* oder *Partizipialkonstruktion* handelt. Aber die Konstruktion zeigt hier einige Besonderheiten.

Eine normale satzwertige Partizipphrase läßt sich zu einem Nebensatz ergänzen. Das verstandene Subjekt entspricht dem des Matrixsatzes. Ob die Partizipphrase temporal, kausal, konditional usw. verstanden wird, bestimmt der Kontext.

> **Aus der Haft entlassen**, nahm er seine ärztliche Tätigkeit wieder auf.
> **Nachdem er** aus der Haft entlassen **worden war** …

## Analyse des Beispiels

Vergleichen wir eine abgewandelte Variante des Ausgangsbeispiels und versuchen, sie zu einem Nebensatz zu ergänzen.

> Die Versuchspersonen schlafen sieben Stunden, **den Wochenendschlaf eingerechnet**.

Da *den Wochenendschlaf* Akkusativ ist, kann nur zu einem Aktiv ergänzt werden. Aber als Subjekt der Partizipphrase wird nicht *die Versuchspersonen* verstanden, sondern unpersönliches *man*. Da Vorzeitigkeit zum Matrixsatz keinen Sinn ergibt, muß außerdem das Partizip in eine finite Präsensform umgewandelt werden. Die Beziehung zum Matrixsatz kann metakommunikativ-konditional verstanden werden.

> Die Versuchspersonen schlafen sieben Stunden, **wenn man** den Wochenendschlaf **einrechnet**.

Für die Besonderheiten der Konstruktion habe ich keine Erklärung.

## Eine verwandte Konstruktion

Eng verwandt dürften kommentierende Partizipien wie die folgenden sein:

> streng genommen, so gesehen, anders ausgedrückt
> → wenn man es streng nimmt, so sieht, anders ausdrückt
>
> Streng genommen gibt es gar keine Eigentumswohnung.
> Wenn man es streng nimmt …

Auch hier kann zu einem konditional verstandenen Präsenssatz im Aktiv ergänzt werden; das Subjekt ist unpersönliches *man*. Da in diesen Fällen kein Akkusativobjekt auftritt, könnte man auch zu einem Passiv ergänzen: *wenn es streng genommen wird* klingt aber ziemlich schlecht.

## Korpusbelege

Der Akkusativ scheint die Regel zu sein.

> Der Vorsitzende des Kreissportbundes, Wilhelm Laaf, hatte gestern unterstrichen, dass diese Lösung – den Kostenfaktor eingerechnet – die sei, die auch den Anforderungen des Vereinssports gerecht würde. (BRZ10/FEB.02043)
>
> Von insgesamt 88 Mitgliedern waren nur elf – den Vorstand eingerechnet – anwesend. (M10/FEB.14718)
>
> Und von den 28 anwesenden Mitgliedern – den Vorstand eingerechnet – wurde niemand „weich“, um die von Lengfeld hinterlassene Lücke auszufüllen. (RHZ13/MAR.34720)
>
> Er malt in dem Stil, der ihm gerade gefällt, das Ergebnis kann sich – den Prominentenbonus eingerechnet – sehen lassen. (Z80/SEP.00057)
>
> Der Betreffende war, den Maßregelvollzug eingerechnet, knapp zehn Jahre in Haft. (PSN/W04.00081)
>
> Joyces Bücher umgibt der Nimbus des Komplizierten. Sogar seine Frau Nora hat es beim "Ulysses" - so Joyce - "nur bis Seite 27 geschafft, den Umschlag eingerechnet". (PRF03/DEZ.00126)

Es soll aber nicht verschwiegen werden, daß sich auch Beispiele mit dem Nominativ finden lassen.

> Heute unterrichten an der Urnäscher Sekundarschule - der Schulleiter eingerechnet - fünf Lehrkräfte. (A98/JUN.43863)
>
> Daneben hatten sich […] genau acht Frauen und fünf Männer in den Speicherer «Linden»-Saal «verirrt», der Berichterstatter eingerechnet. (A99/MAI.37570)
>
> Aber in etwa einhundert Köpfen – der meine eingerechnet – sitzt der Entschluß fest, nicht als Matterhorn-Muffel nach Zermatt zurückzukehren, koste es, was es wolle – und es kostet manchmal sehr viel. (Z69/SEP.00082)

Comment: Ich gewinne den Eindruck, dass (ganz grob gesagt) dann Nominativ verwendet wird, wenn der Einschub Teil des Subjekts des umgebenden Satzes ist: »Fünf Lehrkräfte („und“ der Schulleiter) unterrichten heute ...« (zur Verdeutlichung umgestellt), »Acht Frauen und fünf Männer („und“ der Berichterstatter) hatten sich ... verirrt«. Deswegen würde ich gefühlt auch »[...] waren nur elf – **der** Vorstand eingerechnet – anwesend« schreiben. Bei bspw. »Das Ergebnis kann sich sehen lassen« ist der »Prominentenbonus« kein Teil des Ergebnisses, und der »Maßregelvollzug« nicht Teil des »Betreffende[n]«.

Comment: @Raketenolli Gut beobachtet. Ich persönlich würde den Akkusativ in allen Fällen bevorzugen. Aber unabhängig davon, wie man das bewertet, müßte auf jeden Fall erklärt werden, warum überhaupt Akkusativ stehen kann.

Answer (score 2):

Der Unterschied liegt meiner Meinung nach wohl darin, ob man "eingerechnet" als aktiv oder passiv mit ausgelassenem "ist" auffasst.